# Java Scanner won't read through the whole file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I'm trying to read through a whole file and print its content, which it does. But when I go through it again with a new Scanner to print the content with some section names, it only goes through some of the file.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class FileReader {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt")); 

      while(read.hasNextLine()) {
         System.out.println(read.nextLine());
      } 
      System.out.println();   

      Scanner read2 = new Scanner(new File("sample.txt")); 
      int numQuestions = read2.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Numbers of questions: " + numQuestions);
      System.out.println();

      while(read2.hasNextLine()) {
         int points, numChoices;
         String question, answer;

         if(read2.next().equals("TF")) {
            points = read2.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Points for TF: " + points); 
            read2.nextLine();  // must be done because it does not consume the \n character
            question = read2.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Question for TF: " + question);    
            answer = read2.next();
            System.out.println("Answer for TF: " + answer);
         }
         else if(read2.next().equals("SA")) {
            points = read2.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Points for SA: " + points);
            read2.nextLine();  // must be done because it does not consume the \n character
            question = read2.nextLine();            
            System.out.println("Question for SA: " + question); 
            answer = read2.next();
            System.out.println("Answer for SA: " + answer);
         }
         else if(read2.next().equals("MC")) {
            points = read2.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Points for MC: " + points);
            read2.nextLine();  // must be done because it does not consume the \n character
            question = read2.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Question for MC: " + question);
            read2.nextLine();
            numChoices = read2.nextInt();
            for(int i = 0; i < numChoices; i++) {
               System.out.println(read2.nextLine());
            }
            answer = read2.next();
            System.out.println("Answer for MC: " + answer); 
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the file I'm reading from:

```
3 
TF 5
There exist birds that can not fly. (true/false) 
true 
MC 10 
Who was the president of the USA in 1991? 
6 
Richard Nixon 
Gerald Ford 
Jimmy Carter 
Ronald Reagan 
George Bush Sr. 
Bill Clinton 
E 
SA 20 
What city hosted the 2004 Summer Olympics? 
Athens
```

And here is the output I get:

```
3 
TF 5
There exist birds that can not fly. (true/false) 
true 
MC 10 
Who was the president of the USA in 1991? 
6 
Richard Nixon 
Gerald Ford 
Jimmy Carter 
Ronald Reagan 
George Bush Sr. 
Bill Clinton 
E 
SA 20 
What city hosted the 2004 Summer Olympics? 
Athens

Numbers of questions: 3

Points for TF: 5
Question for TF: There exist birds that can not fly. (true/false) 
Answer for TF: true
```

As you can see, the first `Scanner` reads through the whole file and prints it. But when I try for the second time with the section names, it only goes through question 1's part.

Comment: You use `Scanner read` only once and then create second object of type `Scanner read2`. If you don't need `read` any more, you should use this same variable to create new Scanner object: `read=new Scanner(new File("sample.txt"));`. In this case you have less variables and code is easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks it's because you're scanning 3 times by else-if statement, so you should create a variable `String type = read2.next();` and use it in if-else.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, `read2.next()` reads the next word. When you call it more than once, it reads more than one word.

So when you do

```
 // read a word, and if it's not TF, discard it.
 if(read2.next().equals("TF")) {

 // read another word, and it it's not SA discard it.
 else if(read2.next().equals("SA")) {
```

What you intended is to read the word once and compare it multiple times.  A simple way to do this is to use a switch.

```
// read once,
switch(read.next()) {
    case "TF":
         // do something
         break;

    case "SA":
         // do something
         break;

    // more case(s)
}
```